# Named Event exists even though its creator doesn't

Tags: c++, events, named

Any ideas why:

```
HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, L"Global\\MyEventName");
```

Succeeded opening the event even though the process which created the event is no longer running ?

The only reason I can think about is that the process which created the event, didn't close it when it terminated, BUT, I was under the assumption that if the process which created the named event terminated without closing the event, then the event is closed by OS, Is this a wrong assumption ?

What is the status of named event if its creator terminated without closing it ?

I'm testing on Windows 10 x64, both processes (Creator / OpenEvent) are running as system windows services so privilege issues are out of the game.

Comment: You have the correct assumptions.  Are you absolutely certain beyond a doubt that the process that created the event isn't running?  Or that another service that called CreateEvent isn't running?  And final straw: "MyEventName" is already used by another app? (try changing the event name altogether to something really unique)

Comment: Use [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which objects are open in which processes

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says

> The event object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.

It is not *The event object is destroyed when its creator exited.*

So, it is most probably that there is some another process that has open handle to this event object.

Comment: You're correct, Thanks. This is explaining what I experienced. What are my options to get around that ? Say some other process I don't control opened the event and didn't close it and I do want to recreate this event ?

Comment: @user2906743 the only thing you can do is use a more unique name that only your app(s) use.